# Is there a command line tool that could connect to wifi and takes ssid and pass as arguments?

Tags: command-line, wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

Currently I am using nmtui for selecting a spot.

I would like to connect to a wifi spot from command line.

I expect there might be a tool that would work this way

```
connec2wifi -s somessid -p ****
```

Where -s is ssid and -p is password

or even like this?

```
connec2wifi  somessid *****
```

Also, if there is no such tool. What would be the best way to implement it?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: My operating system is arch

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration/Wireless

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using `nmtui`, you should also have `nmcli`. With that you can
follow the post [Connect to a wireless network using command line nmcli](https://nullr0ute.com/2016/09/connect-to-a-wireless-network-using-command-line-nmcli/).

Check you can see the wireless NIC and that the radio is enabled (basically “Airplane” mode):

```
# nmcli radio
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled 
# nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlan0   wifi      disconnected  --         
eth0    ethernet  unavailable   --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged     --
```

Then to actually connect to a wireless AP:

```
# nmcli device wifi rescan
# nmcli device wifi list
# nmcli device wifi connect SSID-Name password wireless-password
```